# How to share a token in Github Actions Secret

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, token, github-actions

If I put a new token in my Github Actions Secret, how do I use it so that I can share it between my production environment and VS Code?

Is it possible to share my token between Github Actions and VS Code?

[image]

J

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't share the same token in both places.  Create one token for your GitHub Actions secret, and another one for VS Code.  That way, if one of them gets compromised, it doesn't affect the other one.

It's also technically impossible for you to access secrets you put in GitHub Actions, since they're designed such that only the GitHub Actions tooling can access them.  There is no API to get the data back out, which is intentional.

Comment: Right, but how do I put it in VS Code so the code is seemless?

Comment: It depends on the kind of token.  If you're using a GitHub personal access token, just wait to be prompted, and enter your username and then, when prompted for the password, enter your personal access token.  If it's for a different service, you'd have to explain what your service is and how it works.

Comment: I have a Firebase Token.  Where would I put it, in order to share it.  I think I am looking for specific instructions.